# Get daoFactory instance in Vaadin project

Tags: jakarta-ee, instance, vaadin, dao

I'm using `Vaadin` project for the first time and I'm having som troubles.
I did some `data layering` using this [link](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) but the thing now is I want to call the `daoFactory` instance once at the beginning of the application but I didn't know how to do it as the `Vaadin` architecture is quite different from the normal `J2ee` so I couldn't use `servletContextListener`. If anyone has an Idea it will be great.

**DAOFactory used:**

```
public abstract class DAOFactory {

    // Constants ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final String PROPERTY_URL = "url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_DRIVER = "driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_PASSWORD = "password";

    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Returns a new DAOFactory instance for the given database name.
     * @param name The database name to return a new DAOFactory instance for.
     * @return A new DAOFactory instance for the given database name.
     * @throws DAOConfigurationException If the database name is null, or if the properties file is
     * missing in the classpath or cannot be loaded, or if a required property is missing in the
     * properties file, or if either the driver cannot be loaded or the datasource cannot be found.
     */
    public static DAOFactory getInstance(String name) throws DAOConfigurationException {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new DAOConfigurationException("Database name is null.");
        }

        DAOProperties properties = new DAOProperties(name);
        String url = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_URL, true);
        String driverClassName = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_DRIVER, false);
        String password = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_PASSWORD, false);
        String username = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_USERNAME, password != null);
        DAOFactory instance;

        // If driver is specified, then load it to let it register itself with DriverManager.
        if (driverClassName != null) {
            try {
                Class.forName(driverClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new DAOConfigurationException(
                    "Driver class '" + driverClassName + "' is missing in classpath.", e);
            }
            instance = new DriverManagerDAOFactory(url, username, password);
        }

        // Else assume URL as DataSource URL and lookup it in the JNDI.
        else {
            DataSource dataSource;
            try {
                dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(url);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                throw new DAOConfigurationException(
                    "DataSource '" + url + "' is missing in JNDI.", e);
            }
            if (username != null) {
                instance = new DataSourceWithLoginDAOFactory(dataSource, username, password);
            } else {
                instance = new DataSourceDAOFactory(dataSource);
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a connection to the database. Package private so that it can be used inside the DAO
     * package only.
     * @return A connection to the database.
     * @throws SQLException If acquiring the connection fails.
     */
    abstract Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;

    // DAO implementation getters -----------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Returns the User DAO associated with the current DAOFactory.
     * @return The User DAO associated with the current DAOFactory.
     */
    public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return new UserDAOJDBC(this);
    }

    // You can add more DAO implementation getters here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Vaadin you can initialize a Factory this way:

(It's in the main application class)

```
public MyVaadinUI() extends UI 
{
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) 
    {
        // create your Dao instance here
    }
}
```

The init method of the main UI instance is run once per application instance and probably what you want.
The lifecycle of vaadin application, instances, sessions etc. [is described here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.lifecycle.html).
Ping back if you need some more help.

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing part in the copy/paste. I have now corrected the code.
It goes in your main UI class of the vaadin application.

Comment: I don't want to use JPAContainer but the one I already used. I edited my question with the code.

Comment: Sorry, I did now change the example for normal Dao factories and not JPA (But it's at the same place)

Comment: and I I create my instance there how can I access it from other classes? should it be static?